# How do you mathematically generate a matrix where every row is the same vector?

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have some real-valued vector $v$ with dimension $K$. How can I convert $v$ to some matrix $M$ such that each row of $M$ is an instance of $v$? Is there a way to do this mathematically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $v$ is a row vector and $\textbf{1}_K$ the $K$-dimensional vector of ones, then $\textbf{1}_K v^T$ is a matrix with $v$ in each row, where the superscript $T$ is transpose.
Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @David Mitra. Make the difference between $v^T\mathbf{1}$, matrix $1 \times 1$ identified to a scalar, and $\mathbf{1}v^T$, matrix $n \times n$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Thanks; I misinterpreted what "row vector" meant.

Comment: perfect man. that was exactly what i wanted